# PHP Create Dynamic Elements and Sites based on MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Some of you might have seen my previous post about the login.
I now ran into a big problem...
Everything works fine, but now, I want a page, where threads(categories) get loaded by php and mysql.This already works, but I wonder about how I now can click those categories and load all entries in this categorie.
So for example user1 created The Thread Computers.
When I now Click this categorie all entries of this categorie should be loaded, dynamic for sure, because users can create new Threads and the new page would be missing then.
Here is my Code to load all Categories...:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $Mail=$_SESSION['Mail'];


    define('SECURE', true);
    require_once('_connecting.php');

    include '_head.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php echo $error; ?>

    <h1>
        Themen
    </h1>

    <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['Mail'])) {

            echo "
            <html>
                <h1 id='warning'>Ohne Account hast du keinen Zugriff auf diese Seite!!</h1>
                <h2 id='yellowh1'>
                    Die Nutzung unseres Forums setzt einen kostenlosen Account vorraus.
                </h2>
                <h3>Falls du schon einen Account hast, logge dich gleich ein und leg los!<br>
                    Wenn nicht, erstelle dir jetzt in wenigen Schritten deinen Account.

                </h3>

                <img id='stop'src='stop.png' >
                <a href='login.php'><img id='clicker' src='login.png' height='50' width='100'></a>
                <a href='signup.php'><img id='clicker' src='reg.png' height='50' width='150'></a>
            </html>

            ";  

        }

        if (isset($Mail)) {

            $_SESSION['Mail'] = $Mail;
            $_SESSION['Name'] = $user;

            $ss = "SELECT * FROM categories order by cat_id DESC";

            $result = $SQL->query($ss);

            if (!$result) {
                echo 'Die Verbindung zum Datenbank Server ist gescheitert.Versuche es in ein paar Minuten nochmal!Wir arbeiten daran.';
            } else {
                if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
                    echo 'Zurzeit gibt es keine Kategorien... ';
                    echo 'Sei doch der Erste und <a href="newcat.php">erstelle</a> eine! ';

                } else {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                        $date=$row['cat_date'];

                        echo '<div class="thread">';
                        echo '<h1>'.$row['cat_name'].'</h1>';
                        echo '<h2>'.$row['cat_description'].'</h2>';

                        echo' <div id="cat_user"><h3>erstellt von '.$row['cat_user'].'[' .$date.']</h3></div>';

                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        include '_footer.php';
    ?>
```

Comment: You need JavaScript knowledge here, separate PHP site to create some API to consume in browser etc.

Comment: Or maybe you just need wordpress or joomla or any similiar package.

Comment: Okey, i know a little javascript, could you give me a little starting point ? maybe a pseudo code, i dont want you to write my code, but i really dont know how I should start

Comment: @RiggsFolly Why do people always have to give useless answers ?I wont to write the forum myself, i dont want to use CMS's, because then i can say, that i did it alone without any templates, and thats much more fun then clicking 5 things to build your website

Comment: Good for you. My point is, that it is going to take you a long time and judging by the code you show, the end result will not be as good as something you could install and configure in 5 minutes. In development we have a saying "Dont re-invent the wheel" I think it applies here, for your own sanity.

Comment: Yes thats right, but anyway i want to do it by my own, once for the learning effect and sedond for fun. I dont reinvent the wheel i just have fun learning things like this.